# Thingsboard: How to update a attribute to multiple entities using an input-widget

Tags: thingsboard

I want to use the “update server double attribute”-widget to update the same attribute on multiple entities. I created an Alias with a list of entities and used it in the input-widget.

If I use the widget and update an attribute, the attribute is only updated on one entity of the list (the last created entity).

Is there a simple way to solve this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: You could create custom widget by cloning and modifying existing *update server double attribute* widget. Open it from Widget bundles / Input widgets section. Click on Save as and save to your widget bundle (new one). Then modify `updateAttribute` function to walk through all datasources (use `self.ctx.datasources` array) instead of getting the first one (see line `var datasource = self.ctx.datasources[0];` in  `updateAttribute` function)